# Fetching Data from database as per details

Tags: asp.net

```
string date = ddlShowDates.SelectedValue.ToString(); 
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT tbl_Shows.ShowTime FROM tbl_Shows INNER JOIN tbl_MovieTimings ON tbl_Shows.ShowId = tbl_MovieTimings.ShowId WHERE tbl_MovieTimings.Date='" + date + "'", con);
```

I want to display show time in dropdownlist as per date is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use sql-parameters instead of string concatenation to prevent sql-injection.

I guess you have a second `DropDownList` which should be filled from the first:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(ddlShowDates.SelectedValue);
string sql = @"SELECT tbl_Shows.ShowTime 
               FROM tbl_Shows 
               INNER JOIN tbl_MovieTimings 
                   ON tbl_Shows.ShowId = tbl_MovieTimings.ShowId
               WHERE tbl_MovieTimings.Date=@Date";
using(var con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = date;
    con.Open();
    using(var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
       while(rd.Read())
       {
           TimeSpan time = rd.GetTimeSpan(0); 
           timeDropDownList.Items.Add(time.ToString());// change format as desired in TimeSpan.ToString
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: timeDropDwonList.Items.Add(rd.GetDateTime(0).ToString()); Give errors "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: @user2220144: so what type is the column `ShowTime `?

Comment: datatype of column ShowTime is time(7)

Comment: DateTime time = rd.GetDateTime(0); Give errors "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: @user2220144: then it's a `TimeSpan` in C#, give me a minute, i'll edit the answer.... done

Comment: Sure, and datatype of Date is date

Comment: The code which u have given works perfectly fine ...Keep it up